# Rails nested attribute preselect dropdown collection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

in an typical rails application recently I encountered an situation where a single User will have many addresses.
Address will have Country and state as drop downbox.

When a user try to enter an Address he will select the **country** and **onchange** of the country, the state drop down box will be loaded and user can select the approriate state for the country.

using some basic javascript I done the above and while display the data for Edit action I find it difficut to pre select the state drop downbox.

because based on the user selected country I populated the state dropdown but preselecting the state drop down is little trick since it's rails 4 nested attributes form..
[image]

Any help highly appriciated.

[image]

Comment: If you're using form object and have correctly loaded all associations then it should shown preselected/saved info in dropdown. Please show us your code so that we can see what's the issue. We can not anticipate anything by looking at a picture.

Comment: please add code in html file for the form